# Error: Connection refused while token generating via WSO2 Devportal

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring WSO2 fully distributed APIM  3.1.0 with IS as KM and Dev/Publisher in one node. My IPs are as below,

- Gateway IP - `172.42.42.20` DNS: `gw.local.com`
- ISKM IP - `172.42.42.40` DNS: `iskm.local.com`
- Dev/Publisher - `172.42.42.80` DNS: `apim.local.com`

All the configurations are done following [WSO2 documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/) and [ansible scripts](https://github.com/wso2/ansible-apim/tree/3.1.x). But an error occurred while generating tokens via devportal. Using the curl command the tokens can be generated successfully. How to fix this issue? The carbon log is below. I saw many fixes for this issue, but none worked.

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2020-07-13 08:13:07,571] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Error while creating tokens - Connection refused (Connection refused) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:681)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:524)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest_aroundBody50(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:775)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:773)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken_aroundBody10(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:385)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:304)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken_aroundBody30(APIConsumerImpl.java:1341)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken(APIConsumerImpl.java:1320)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGenerateTokenPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:636)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGenerateTokenPost(ApplicationsApi.java:201)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2020-07-13 08:13:07,590] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl} - Error while re-generating AccessToken org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while creating tokens - Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException_aroundBody6(AbstractKeyManager.java:165)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:163)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken_aroundBody10(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:411)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:304)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken_aroundBody30(APIConsumerImpl.java:1341)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken(APIConsumerImpl.java:1320)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGenerateTokenPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:636)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGenerateTokenPost(ApplicationsApi.java:201)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:681)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:524)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest_aroundBody50(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:775)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:773)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken_aroundBody10(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:385)
... 57 more
```

Comment: Hi, @Ji hu la were you able to solve this? I am also getting the same exception while generating a token.

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan Hi, yes, It because I used hostnames. If you are using hostnames, add them to the `/etc/hosts` file and change the IPs into hostnames configured in the `deployment.toml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like the Devportal is unable to connect to the key manager (IS as KM). Check the following config in the deployment.toml of the dev portal and it should point to IS as KM.

```
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://[IS-AS-KM-host]/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
```

Comment: It is connected as below and still doesn't work
`[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://iskm.local.com:9443/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hostnames, add them to the `/etc/hosts` file and change the IPs into hostnames configured in the `deployment.toml`