# Error while key generation in WSO2 IS as Key Manager 5.10.0 and WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 all-in-one instance configured with WSO2 IS as Key Manager.

- APIM 3.1.0
- ISKM 5.10.0

I am using DNS names as `api.dev.com` and `is.dev.com`. Both are running on two VMs on port 9443

I am referring to this [WSO2 documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/) and WSO2 ansible scripts.

I made the configurations according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872067/error-connection-refused-while-token-generating-via-wso2-devportal/63387791#63387791) as well. But still, it gives the error as,

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2020-08-13 03:40:08,355] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Error while creating tokens - Connection refused (Connection refused) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:681)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:524)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest_aroundBody50(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:775)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.executeHTTPrequest(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:773)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken_aroundBody10(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:385)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:304)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken_aroundBody30(APIConsumerImpl.java:1341)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken(APIConsumerImpl.java:1320)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGenerateTokenPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:636)
at 
..
..
.. MORE
```

Comment: What is the port for is.dev.com? Is it running on 9444 or 443? Based on the port, change the key manager configuration

Comment: @Pubci both are running on 9443

Comment: in etc\host file add something like this 127.0.0.1       localhost.com, OR  in toml file

Comment: If you havent used proxy ports then service url of KM should have the port 9443. service_url = "https://[IS-AS-KM-host:9443]/services/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in etc\host file add something like this 127.0.0.1       localhost.com, OR  in deployment.toml file add [transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"